# SQL 2008 Performance Reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql, database-performance

Does anybody know of DMV's or reports that will show the historical performance of the stored procedures on the server? Also if that data is stored in a table or tables, what is the retention period and can it be adjusted?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this blog post:

http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2008/01/21/five-dmv-queries-that-will-make-you-a-superhero/

It will show some DMV queries that will show the mostly costly stored procedures by various measurements. For example, one of the included queries is for logical reads:

```
-- Get Top 20 executed SP's ordered by logical reads (memory pressure)
    SELECT TOP 20 qt.text AS 'SP Name', total_logical_reads,
    qs.execution_count AS 'Execution Count', total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count AS 'AvgLogicalReads',
    qs.execution_count/DATEDIFF(Second, qs.creation_time, GetDate()) AS 'Calls/Second',
    qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS 'AvgWorkerTime',
    qs.total_worker_time AS 'TotalWorkerTime',
    qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count AS 'AvgElapsedTime',
    qs.total_logical_writes,
    qs.max_logical_reads, qs.max_logical_writes, qs.total_physical_reads,
    DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GetDate()) AS 'Age in Cache', qt.dbid
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt
    WHERE qt.dbid = db_id() -- Filter by current database
    ORDER BY total_logical_reads DESC
```